# New-Pssession in runspace does not connect to remote exchange server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, runspace

I am trying to import Exchange Server session into runspace.addscript({
it is something like below

```
$PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
                $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
                #$PowerShell.AddCommand({New-PSSession});
                #$PowerShell.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
                #$PowerShell.AddParameter("ConnectionUri","http://win2012-2/PowerShell/");
                #$PowerShell.AddParameter("Credential", $ExchangeCredential);
                #$PowerShell.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");
                $PowerShell.AddScript({ 
                                        param($FileName,$FilePath,$i_f)
                                        [console]::WriteLine("script")
                                        $User = "localdomain\administrator"
                                        $Pass = "********"
                                        $ExchangeCredential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $User, $Pass                                         
                                        $ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://win2012-2/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $ExchangeCredential 
                                        $Session  = Import-PSSession $ExchangeSession -AllowClobber
                                        $state = $Session.SessionState
                                        [console]::WriteLine($state) | FT
```

But i could not get session information from $Session object or $state object,
how can i import the exchange session to runspace script?
any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`[console]::WriteLine("foo")` does not work inside a runspace, so you don't see any input. You can get around this by passing your current console's details (`$host`) to your scriptblock

I know you commented them out, but any parameters you're adding should be defined in the `param()` of your script block

I only have exchange-online, but this should work pretty similarly for either

```
# example of getting cred once at start
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

# create the PS session and assign a runspace
$PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
  $PowerShell.Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
  $PowerShell.Runspace.Open()

# First, the script block
$Scriptblock = {
  param($cred,$console)
  
  # use $cred defined as a parameter
  $ExchSession = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Authentication Basic 
  Import-PSSession $ExchSession -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber

  # test session and output to console
  $m = get-mailbox user@domain.com
  $console.UI.WriteLine($m.name)

  Remove-PSSession $ExchSession
}

# Then add the script block to your runspace
# add Arguments in order, or add named Parameters
$powershell.AddScript($Scriptblock)        | out-null
  $powershell.AddArgument($UserCredential) | out-null
  $powershell.AddArgument($host)           | out-null

# run
$invokeInfo = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

# wait for completion, check output...

$PowerShell.Runspace.Dispose()
$PowerShell.Dispose()
```